# quickest way to get ethernet port carrier info when port is administratively down

Tags: linux, python-3.x, network-programming, ubuntu-14.04, ethernet

I have more than ten ethernet ports (no wireless etc). When the port
is **administratively** down, what is **quickest** way to find if a port has a carrier?

Just for demonstration purpose, I have a eth3 port administratively down 
and has carrier (physical link). I have the below working code. How ever, 
when I delete the 5 seconds delay, I get no carrier (though there is really
carrier).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.4

import subprocess
import time

def func():
    try:
        with open("/sys/class/net/eth3/carrier") as cf1:
            carrier = cf1.read().strip()
    except Exception as e:
        cmd = "ip link set dev eth3 up"
        result = subprocess.check_output(cmd, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True, universal_newlines=True)
        time.sleep(5)
        with open("/sys/class/net/eth3/carrier") as cf1:
            carrier = cf1.read().strip()
        cmd = "ip link set dev eth3 down"
        result = subprocess.check_output(cmd, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True, universal_newlines=True)
    return carrier

c = func()
print("eth3 carrier: {0}".format(c))
```

Comment: If your driver turns off the hardware that detects the carrier, you won't be able to know.  Have you considered leaving the interface up but dropping all incoming traffic?

Comment: This doesn't sound like a Python question.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Thanks for your reply. Yes, I proposed to keep the interface up, but I was shot down on that idea :-(.

Comment: @ColinSchoen: The code is in python, so is the tag. I dont mind deleting that tag.

Comment: I moved on with multi-threading - it is reasonable fast. But I really appreciate if there are better thoughts.